# HttpPostedFile.SaveAs() throws UnauthorizedAccessException even though the file is saved?

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, iis-7

I have an aspx page with multiple `FileUpload` controls and one Upload button. In the click handler I save the files like this:

```
string path = "...";
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count - 1; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[i];
    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    string saveAsPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
    file.SaveAs(saveAsPath);
}
```

When `file.SaveAs()` is called, it throws:

> System.Web.HttpUnhandledException:
>   Exception of type
>   'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException'
>   was thrown. --->
>   System.UnauthorizedAccessException:
>   Access to the path
>   '...'
>   is denied.    at
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32
>   errorCode, String maybeFullPath)    at
>   System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access,
>   Int32 rights, Boolean useRights,
>   FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize,
>   FileOptions options,
>   SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)    at
>   System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options,
>   String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String
>   path, FileMode mode)    at
>   System.Web.HttpPostedFile.SaveAs(String
>   filename)    at
>   Belden.Web.Intranet.Iso.Complaints.AttachmentUploader.btnUpload_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs
>   e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception
>   e)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean
>   includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()
>   at
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   ASP.departments_iso_complaints_uploadfiles_aspx.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Now here's the fun part. The file is saved correctly! So why is it throwing this exception?

**Update**

I fixed it by checking for a non zero ContentLength:

```
string path = "...";
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count - 1; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[i];
    if (file.ContentLength == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }

    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    string saveAsPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
    file.SaveAs(saveAsPath);
}
```

Comment: Try removing/moving the file from where it is saved as of now & upload it again. In this case, does the error still occur?

Comment: I just stepped through the code again ... The error was happening when one of the FileUpload controls didn't have a path. It still creates an instance of HttpPostedFile, but the ContentLength is 0 and FileName is empty. Doh!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it by checking for a non zero ContentLength:

```
string path = "...";
for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count - 1; i++)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = Request.Files[i];
    if (file.ContentLength == 0)
    {
        continue;
    }

    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
    string saveAsPath = Path.Combine(path, fileName);
    file.SaveAs(saveAsPath);
}
```

Sometimes its the simple things that I overlook ...

Answer (score 2):

try to use

`file.SaveAs(server.mappath(saveAsPath));`

Answer (score 1):

Interesting... my first question is, are you *absolutely* sure that really is the line of code that is throwing the exception?

Two... does it go away if you (temporarily) grant Everyone access to that path?

How are your permissions set up now?  What user is running ASP.NET?  Are you using impersonation?