# Grab contents of System.Web.HttpPostedFileBase and write to disk

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Really not sure how to go about this, but I need to grab the contents from the posted file and write them to disk.

Here is the code I'm looking at.
This is a function to upload the file:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult UploadInvoice()
{
    foreach (var file in Request.Files.AllKeys)
    {
        var tempFile = Request.Files[file];
        if (tempFile != null && tempFile.ContentLength > 0)
        {

            var fileName = tempFile.FileName;

            string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "content\\files\\Customer-Returns\\Invoices");
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
            filePath = filePath + fileName;

            using (var fs = new FileStream(Request.Files[file], FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    fs.CopyTo(ms);
                    byte[] rawdata = ms.GetBuffer();

                    using (var o = System.IO.File.Create(filePath))
                    {
                        ms.CopyTo(o);
                        fs.Close();
                        ms.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return Json(new { result = true });
}
```

I have an exception here:

[image]

Not sure exactly how to go about this, and can't seem to find a clear example.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HttpPostedFile.SaveAs() throws UnauthorizedAccessException even though the file is saved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2655340/httppostedfile-saveas-throws-unauthorizedaccessexception-even-though-the-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I was going about this completely wrong and idn't realize it would be so easy.

As @mjwills pointed out above I had to use the `SaveAs` method.
Here is the code

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UploadInvoice()
    {
        foreach (var file in Request.Files.AllKeys)
        {
            var tempFile = Request.Files[file];
            if (tempFile != null && tempFile.ContentLength > 0)
            {

                var fileName = tempFile.FileName;

                string filePath = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "content\\files\\Customer-Returns\\Invoices\\");
                DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
                filePath = filePath + fileName;

                Request.Files[file].SaveAs(filePath);
            }
        }

        return Json(new { result = true });
    }
```

Comment: Remove `AllKeys` and make the other required changes to make it compile. The code will be shorter, simpler and faster.